# Setup properties are incorrect

Tags: installation

I have a a setup file. if i right click  on setup file. In its properties and detail; version number and product name are not shown on Vista. but on XP it is fine. Any help will highly Appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Comment: Valid question if you're a setup developer like myself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Vista and Windows 7 only show extended properties for files on a local disk, if the setup is on a network share try copying it to your desktop first.